# Angular9 get parent node on element added with ng-container and ngIf

Tags: css, angular, dom

I am trying to get the parent element when a ng-template is added with `ngIf`.

Layout:

```
<section>
  <h2>
    Hello!
    <ng-container *ngIf="someCondition1; then myTemplate"></ng-container>
  </h2>

  <div>
    Another one!
    <ng-container *ngIf="someCondition2; then myTemplate"></ng-container>
  </div>

  <!-- More markup here that show myTemplate based on conditions -->
</section>

<ng-template #myTemplate>
  <img src="path/to/image.png" />
</ng-template>
```

The above works fine but I want to grab the parent element of wherever it's added and apply some styles to the parent in the typescript file. Can I use one of the lifecycle functions or select the parent another way whenever the template is added to the DOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I had to add a template tag on the image and then grab it with `ViewChildren` of type `QueryList`. This gave me access to the native element of each one where I could grab the parent node. This has to to be done in the `AfterViewInit` lifecycle hook.

HTML:

```
<section>
  <h2>
    Hello!
    <ng-container *ngIf="someCondition1; then myTemplate"></ng-container>
  </h2>

  <!-- More markup here that show myTemplate based on conditions -->
</section>

<ng-template #myTemplate>
  <img #myTemplateImage src="path/to/image.png" />
</ng-template>
```

Typescript:

```
import { Component, ViewChildren, ElementRef, QueryList, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'test-selector',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html'
})
export class TestComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChildren('myTemplateImage') imageList: QueryList<ElementRef>;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.imageList.forEach((item) => {
      item.nativeElement.parentNode.style.fontStyle = 'italic';
    });
  }
}
```